# d3 chart's tooltip fails to parse February 2009 correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an area chart that parses dates for the tooltip correctly -- except when it comes to February 2009.

Here's a Plunker demonstrating the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yl4hUDVin2sZedu016Wm?p=preview

Here, I think, is the problematic code:

```
  var mousex = d3.mouse(this);
  mousex = mousex[0] ;//+ 3; //7
  var invertedx = xScale.invert(mousex);
  var invertedxmo = xScale.invert(mousex);
  var invertedxyr = xScale.invert(mousex);

  function getMonth(date) {
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    return month < 10 ? '0' + month : '' + month; 
  }

  invertedx = ("" + (invertedx.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + invertedx.getFullYear();
  var selected = (d.values);

  for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
    dates[k] = selected[k].x
    dates[k] = ("" + (dates[k].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + dates[k].getFullYear();
  } 
  invertedxmo = ("" + (invertedxmo.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) ;
  var selectedmo = (d.values);

  for (var m = 0; k < selectedmo.length; k++) {
    dates[m] = selectedmo[m].x
    dates[m] = ("" + (dates[m].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) ;
  }       
  invertedxyr = invertedxyr.getFullYear();

  mousedate = dates.indexOf(invertedx);
  pro = d.values[mousedate].y

  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
```

I've tried changing `slice(-2)`, and that fixes the problem for February 2009, but it also creates a new problem for parsing December dates for every year.

Can anyone demonstrate how to fix this?

**Edit/Update:**
Interestingly, when I tinkered with the chart's date range by changing line 16 from `var startDate = d3.time.month.offset(new Date(), -108);` to `var startDate = d3.time.month.offset(new Date(), -119);`, then February 2009 parses just fine —  but February 2008 throws an error! Same, too, if I narrow the date range by changing line 16's offset value to `-98`: February 2010 throws an error, but all subsequent Februaries parse just fine, as do all other dates. (Obviously, if you use the slider, instead, to narrow the date range, the error will still only occur in the first February that was displayed when the chart initially loaded, before the slider was moved.)

So it seems that it's always the **first** February on the chart that produces this error, no matter whether the date range beings in 2008, 2009, 2010, etc. All subsequent Februaries after the first are parsed just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the code in the mouseover code. The issue lies in the **DATE**

Today's date is 30th and the way you're generating the start-date is:

```
d3.time.month.offset(new Date(), -108);
```

i.e. it starts with `Sun Nov 30 2008 16:46:58 GMT-0500 (EST)` and goes on the following way:

```
Sun Nov 30 2008 16:52:32 GMT-0500 (EST)
Tue Dec 30 2008 16:52:32 GMT-0500 (EST)
Fri Jan 30 2009 16:52:32 GMT-0500 (EST)
Mon Mar 02 2009 16:52:32 GMT-0500 (EST)
Thu Apr 02 2009 16:52:32 GMT-0400 (EDT)
.....
```

As it couldn't find a 30th in February 2009, it ends up picking up March 2nd 2009 and from there onwards, every 2nd day of the month is picked which will surely include all Februarys. (in the `createDatesArr` function)

**One approach** would be to start from the 1st day of the month.

**Relevant code:**

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1);
var startDate = d3.time.month.offset(firstDay, -108);
```

Updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/40nrfdPAMkK1yDmrIYm7?p=preview)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: That works-- thanks so much! Curiously enough, I actually noticed that this problem started occurring on Monday of this week, which was 27 November. I suppose 27 and 28 February were just close enough to the 29th and 30th to trigger some unexpected boundary behavior.

Comment: Glad I could help! Nope, here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/auiRfCqmIKDgoUotTBn6?p=preview) using November 27th to decide the start date. It doesn't mess up, that might be something else (not sure what). Use console logs/adding breakpoints as much as you can, it helps a lot debugging.